# table is not being responsive with css properly on smaller devices?

Tags: html, css

I am coming to a problem where I am trying to make my table responsive. It work in this case but `table-layout: fixed;` make it worked but, when I resize my columns get together. I use `word-break: break-word;` but it just made my text squished. When I comment the `table-layout:fixed` and resize browser it gets my data crushed. How to make it responsive in my code below. thanks for the help.

Here is my code:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: auto;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

thead,
tfoot {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 18px);
}

tbody {
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-break: break-word
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 1</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 2</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 3</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 4</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 5</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 6</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 7</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 8</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="left-header">Test</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $57.36</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $58.94</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $60.56</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $62.23</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $65.70</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $69.37</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $73.23</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $77.31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="left-header">Test</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $4,588.80</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $4,715.20</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $4,844.80</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $4,978.40</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $5,256.00</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $5,549.60</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $5,858.40</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $6,184.80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="left-header">Test</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $119,767.68</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $123,066.72</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $126,449.28</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $129,936.24</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $137,181.60</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $144,844.56</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $152,904.24</td>
      <td class="left-header"> $161,423.28</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use table. You can do the same with Divs and CSS to get more control. 
But if you really need, i suggest this approach:

```css
table {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

thead th {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}


/* You will need to display:none the duplicated header in responsible-table-item*/

tr.responsive-table-item .responsive-table-cell {
  display: none
}


/* Add screen proportion or class when break occurs */

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  /* Hide table headers */
  .table-header {
    display: none;
  }
  tr.responsive-table-item {
    display: block;
  }
  tr.responsive-table-item .responsive-table-cell {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  tr.responsive-table-item td:first-child {
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  tr.responsive-table-item td,
  tr.responsive-table-item th {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(50% - 22px);
    /* Cell Border + padding*/
    word-break: break-all;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="table-header">
      <th></th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 1</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 2</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 3</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 4</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 5</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 6</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 7</th>
      <th class="right-header">Step 8</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Using this way, you will need to duplicate your table header in each TR to use in mobile display -->
    <tr class="responsive-table-item">
      <td class="left-header">Test</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 1</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $57.36</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 2</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $58.94</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 3</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $60.56</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 4</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $62.23</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 5</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $65.70</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 6</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $69.37</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 7</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $73.23</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 8</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $77.31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="responsive-table-item">
      <td class="left-header">Test</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 1</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $4,588.80</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 2</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $4,715.20</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 3</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $4,844.80</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 4</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $4,978.40</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 5</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $5,256.00</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 6</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $5,549.60</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 7</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $5,858.40</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 8</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $6,184.80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="responsive-table-item">
      <td class="left-header">Test</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 1</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $119,767.68</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 2</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $123,066.72</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 3</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $126,449.28</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 4</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $129,936.24</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 5</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $137,181.60</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 6</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $144,844.56</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 7</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $152,904.24</td>
      <th class="responsive-table-cell">Step 8</th>
      <td class="left-header"> $161,423.28</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what happen to my `class="odd"` ?

Comment: I apply your code and still it does resize the table

Comment: Man, if you need "odd" class you can append `class="responsive-table-item odd"`. You are doing something wrong. If you run this snippet above, the code don't work? Put all inside one [codepen] (https://codepen.io/) and send here.

Comment: But, I am telling you that when you resize it wont be as a mobile view. I don't want to use the button though. Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQaWrN

Comment: try to resize your browser and see if the table does shrink into mobile

Comment: Man the button is only for demo purpose, you need to read snippet before apply in your code, at css i write `"Add screen proportion or class when break occurs"` you need to uncomment the code of media query and replace to your mobile proportion.

Comment: Okay, I made it easier and edited the snippet again. Note that, here at stackoverflow, the resizes consider the width of snippet view ... Not of your display, you will need to replace "400px" to size of break occurs in your application. Here is the pen: https://codepen.io/Gcruz/pen/YRaKgM

Answer (score 2):

There is no way with this long columns. You have to re think something different for responsive layouts (May be stacking the columns with relevant headers). Its the same principal applies to html emails.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried this instead:

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
   <table>
     ...
   </table>
</div>
```

and get rid of other CSS

Comment: I don't want to use a scrollbar - though.

Comment: and is not being responsive anyhow.

Comment: you still need  table { width: 100% } CSS property

Comment: For table this width you probably need a scroll bar. There is no more elegant way  as I know of... unfortunately

Comment: In my code above works perfectly. Is only my text getting squished when I resize my browser.

Comment: I applied your snippet. and is still showing this way: https://imgur.com/a/Th1Zo5L

Comment: Use device toolbar in Chrome DevTools